# Is the language of all DFAs that accept the empty language regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-automata

Is $E_{DFA}$ in the class of regular languages?

$\qquad E_{DFA} =  \{ \langle D \rangle \mid D \text{ is a DFA }, L(D) = \emptyset\}$

My argument is that it is because all of the DFAs in $E_{DFA}$ can be reduced to a DFA that only accepts on no input. Is this right?

Comment: Regular languages have a very limited structure. There's no reason for $E_{DFA}$ to be regular. It should be easy to show by multiple methods, e.g., using pumping lemma.

Comment: For other possible methods, refer to [How to prove that a language is not regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular)

Comment: What kind of encoding is $<.>$ ?

Comment: What a weird exercise problem. Does it maybe say "minimal DFA" in the original?

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.